# doxygen: custom latex commands not working in html with mathjax

Tags: doxygen, mathjax

I'm writing a documentation.
I defined a set of custom commands that i give to the doxyfile, using

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES = ../../user_manual/latex_sources_for_advanced_stuff/extra_basic_commands
```

When I compile the doc to obtain a pdf, it works well. However, in html, it works only if I don't use mathjax, otherwise I get an error:

```
Undefined control sequence \foobar
```

I don't understand how to also give my package to mathjax ? (if it is possible)

Thanks

Comment: I assume that your LaTeX parts are part of formulas. Here there are some limited possibilities to add your own code. See the options MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS and MATHJAX_CODEFILE in the Doxyfile. One is of course limited to the possibilities of MathJax

Comment: hi. I saw this in the mathajx doc. But as far as i understand, i need to translate all the macro in the sty file into a mathjax understandable language, which is to much effort for the benefit...

Comment: Since MathJax is not TeX it is not possible to simply import TeX code such as sty files. If your file only contains macro definitions using def, newcommand etc. then you could work around this difference and e.g insert its content at the top of the html body in a hidden span. Make sure to wrap the contents of the file in math delimiters so MathJax processes them.

Comment: It does only containt macro definitions with def and newcommands. However, i don't see how to do what you suggest in doxygen. Could you provide a simple example please?